# Samba Domain Setup

Tags: server, permissions, samba, manpage, domain-server

I have set up UBUNTU Server on an HP-Proliant.
Idea is a simple SMB-File Server setup with restricted User rights in a mixed Win/Lin/OSx LAN

To achieve this I thought out a domain setup with samba.
Due to lag of proper DVD-drive we used the mini-iso for install.

Although I have followed a huge amount of man-pages and the samba is running ( i can see the shares) I do fail to register clients to the domain or handle the access rights.

Windows User Rights are not able to access the server, lifting them into the winnt domain on Ubuntu fails.

All documentation I found is old and does only apply partially so I wonder if there is actually a full step-by-step guide that applies to the recent Ubuntu server revision and packages. ???

Due to my limited linux server knowledge I am depending on man-guides to achieve my stuff.THus I am pretty frustrated with not getting where I want to be

thx

Answer (score 0):

Im running a Samba server on the HP-Proliant aswell.

My Setup as follow. 2 accounts - DPUSER and DPUSER1

DPUSER1 have the highest level of access.
DPUSER have limited access.

Also make sure you added your users to Ubuntu and to the samba server.

Adding user to samba.....
smbpasswd -a [username_here]

In the Smb.conf file make sure that the following its setup right

Your workgroup is set to your network. 
workgroup = WORKGROUP 
wins support = yes ( make sure the # isnt infront)

Right at the bottom.....mine follows

[Master Drive]

```
    comment = Mater drive files
    path = /home/srv/master
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    valid users = dpuser dpuser1
    writeable = yes
    directory mask = 0777
    create mask = 0777
    write list = dpuser dpuser1
```

[Accounts]

```
    comment = Accounts Files
    path = /home/srv/accounts
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    #guest ok = yes
    valid users = dpuser1
    create mask = 0777
```